# I want a word "Distinction" those who got Greater Than=80 and "Fail" if a person got marks less than =35

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My question is:
[image]

I tried following Query :

```
db.marks.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"students",localField:"StudentId",foreignField:'_id',as:"students"}}, {$unwind:{path:"$Result"}},
  {$project:{_id:0,"Result.Subject":1,"Result.Marks":1,"students.Name":1}},{$match:{"Result.Marks":{$gte:70}}}
  ])
```

and I am expecting to add those "Distinction" who got more than 80 marks

Comment: You need to [`$map`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#mongodb-expression-exp.-map) the array.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any reasons to use aggregation. Try this:

```js
db.marks.updateMany({
  "$expr": { "$gt": [{ "$sum": "$Result.Marks" }, 80] }
}, {
    "$set": {
        "Distinction": true
    }
});
db.marks.updateMany({
  "$expr": { "$lt": [{ "$sum": "$Result.Marks" }, 35] }
}, {
    "$set": {
        "Distinction": true
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you updating the documents? It's not what the OP wants

Comment: I don't really understand the question, in that case.

"I am expecting to add those "Distinction" who got more than 80 marks"
OP, You want this during aggregation, or in the documents themselves?